# Load video thumbnail in jetpack compose using coil

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm using coil `2.2.0` with compose `1.2.1`. I've tried below code to load video thumbnail from remote url but it's not working. Any solution?

I've tried below code but it's not working. Any solution?

```
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url)
        .fetcherFactory<Any> { data, options, imageLoader ->
            imageLoader.components.newBuilder()
                .add(VideoFrameDecoder.Factory())
                .build()
                .newFetcher(data, options, imageLoader)?.first
        }
        .videoFrameMillis(1000)
        .build(),
)
Image(painter = painter, contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: Try adding a listener to the image request & check the error in `onError` callback. Also check that you have the Internet permission added.

Comment: Already have all permissions. My video URL does not end with video extension (e.g., .mp4) and Coil does not such URL. That is the issue.

Comment: If the filename does not end with a valid extension, you need to implement a `decoderFactory`, check valid extensions here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-formats. Also check this Coil documentation: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/videos/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution could work for you (answered at [Coil does not load video frame in Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835125/coil-does-not-load-video-frame-in-image/76681308#76681308))

```
@Composable
fun VideoThumbnail(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    url: String = "",
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { ImageView(it).loadVideoUrl(url) },
        update = { it.loadVideoUrl(url) }
    )
}

fun ImageView.loadVideoUrl(url: String) = this.apply {
    load(url) {
        decoderFactory { result, options, _ ->
            VideoFrameDecoder(
                result.source,
                options
            )
        }
    }
    scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
}
```